# How to import from OneNote on Windows to the Mac edition of OneNote?

Tags: mac, ms-office, onenote

I have been working on Windows 7 with Microsoft OneNote 2010. I have a huge amount of work store in OneNote.

I need to open those notebooks in OneNote running on OS X 10.9, Mavericks, which has been recently released. Is there a way to do so?

After successfully importing, I plan to continue working on the Mac edition of OneNote.

If OneNote on the Mac can not do this, are there any other applications on the Mac, like EverNote or Growly, which can import my work from Windows OneNote and let me continue on my Mac int the way I was doing in Windows?

Comment: I have the same problem and have tried the solutions Steve and Graham gave us, but it doesn't work! When i put my OneNote-package in my online OneDrive (onedrive.live.com) and try to get it through OneDrive in the OneNote App (on mac) i doesn't give me the opportunity to pick them. They aren't even there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I exported my work OneNote file in Office 2010 this way. File tab -> Save As -> Notebook ->OneNote Package.

OneNote on the Mac imports that notebook with no problems (or at least it did for me). And syncing with a (free) MS cloud account works great as well.

It seems to work largely the same as OneNote for Windows.

As for other applications. The only other program like this I tried was Evernote. But I was disappointed that it would **not** import styled text. So you lose all your formatting (tables, lists, pictures). The only way I found to import OneNote files into Evernote was to paste a screen shot of the page, hardly a good solution.

Comment: Export and Import features are worth trying. I will try it out. I just remember I did not considered that MAC version of OneNote works online. it doesn't save Notebooks locally. While with windows version of OneNote I had all my Notebooks saved locally. Although online notebooks is good feature but I am not ready for this at the moment. So is there a way for this to keep local notebooks in MAC version of OneNote. I am convinced of OneNote being feature rich and better than most of other solutions on MAC and PC. But what I do with above issues.

Comment: As of now (May 1, 2014), OneNote for Mac only supports saving to the cloud.  It doesn't support local notebooks at this time.

Comment: Is there a way to create sort of 'local cloud' on your LAN to achieve this?

Comment: Steve Chambers -->  "OneNote on the Mac imports that notebook with no problems" (or at least it did for me)"  I did not see any 'Import' feature in MAC free version of OneNote so I can not import anything locally too.

Comment: Looking back on my answer I SHOULD have said "just open the exported OneNote file (Command-O") rather than "import." As OneNote for Mac will directly open the file exported by OneNote for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

### Synchronising Notes Between OneNote Editions

Upgrade to the latest OneNote on your Windows computer. This edition is compatible with the Mac edition of OneNote.

Once upgraded, you will be able to synchronise your files through Microsoft's cloud services. This will allow you to work on your OneNote files on both Mac or Windows.

The latest [OneNote is free](http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/17/onenote-now-on-mac-free-everywhere-and-service-powered/) on both Mac and Windows.

### Mac Alternatives to OneNote

If you do not like OneNote on the Mac, a number of Mac apps exist that import OneNote files. This discussion, [can i transfer microsoft onenote to macbook](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20932388#20932388), suggests [GrowlyBird](http://growlybird.com/GrowlyBird/Notes.html).

If you want specific alternative recommendations, ask a new software recommendation question mentioning where the free Mac OneNote does not meet your needs. Others with more exposure to alternatives should then be better able to help.

Comment: Ok, now how do I do this without any of my files going through Microsoft's cloud services?

Comment: @Michael please can you ask a new question. Doing so will attract answers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: From the Windows OneNote (v2010 for me), sync your files to MS's cloud drive service.  Then open the Notebooks from the Mac client.

There is no way to import a notebook on the Mac version 15.8.

Comment: It seems the way to get my stuff in OneNote MAC is only by using MS cloud service in between. That's fine and I will try that out. I also discovered later that MAC OneNote has no option to save your work locally, rather it saves online on MS cloud only. That's also a point of concern to me. So till now I am using my OneNote on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a one way to open a Windows OneNote notebook in the OSX version of Onenote.  I am particularly interested in opening a Notebook located on a Sharepoint server in a corporate environment and this met my needs.  This article describes the technique:
http://www.benstegink.com/adding-sharepoint-onenote-notebook-onenote-mac/ 
Basically one must open the notebook in a windows machine, grab a link to an object in the notebook, send the link to the mac and then click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

I opened my old OneNote Notebook in Windows, Onenote 2010, and also opened a Notebook already stored in the OneDrive cloud (accessible by Mac).

I then clicked on each tab of my old Notebook and copied it into the OneDrive cloud Notebook.  I clicked on Sync in the Windows version and then everyone was updated.  I could then abandon the Windows version and just use the cloud version via Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded OneNote on Windows to the latest version. In the installation process, it says files of old version failed to convert, but that's fine. Once you're done with the installation, open the software where you can find the old OneNote files. Click on property of each notes, convert it to the  2013 version, sync it. Then go back to your Mac; now you can find those notes in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about import/export. Make sure you are using the latest version possible on both platforms, and store the Windows OneNote files in the cloud (OneDrive). This will also allow you to access it using the web version. Then invite yourself to share this OneNote notebook with an email address from your Mac You should now be able to get at the content in OneNote on the Mac and edit/move it as required.