# Import old OneNote .one files into OneNote for Mac

Tags: onenote

I have some old OneNote files (with .one) extension from those long ago years when I still suffered from Windows.

Additionally I have some current template files with .one extensions.

I no longer have (or want) access to a Windows machine with or without OneNote.

Does any means exist for me to import such files into my new OneNote for Mac?

Comment: maybe try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129283/how-to-import-from-onenote-on-windows-to-the-mac-edition-of-onenote even though no answer is marked as correct, it may help

Comment: @Tetsujin - Tried all of those before I posted ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is a little out of date:

I used the previous version of OneNote for the mac that actually allowed you to open files locally. Now Microsoft will only let you open files on OneNote for the Mac if it is on Microsoft OneDrive (grrr....)

I tried exporting a section as a .one file and saving it on my OneDrive and OneNote for the Mac would not see the file. So it seems that it won't open .one files and that you would have to open those files on a PC, export them to a OneNote package file and then put them on your OneDrive.

Perhaps you can find a copy of the older version for the Mac, otherwise it looks like you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

researched this for last couple of days and found out there is no such option in OneNote for Mac. However, the Windows version can open .One file. So, all I did was:

1. borrow my neighbor's windows machine (My Dell wont boot up) created
2. Windows user linked to my OneDrive account
3. Opened .one file in the OneNote app
4. Added the notebook to my OneDrive folder.
5. Synched it up on the web.
6. I switched over to my Mac
7. Opened up OneNote app and added the OneNote notebook from my OneDrive folder that I had added from the windows machine

That is what it takes!